# Shiny Server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Sample apps not working

Tags: r, shiny, ubuntu-16.04, shiny-server

I installed Shiny Server and I reached the point where I had it configured but the sample apps are not working as shown in the screenshot, and I wonder what the next step should be.

[image]

The session info is as follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8      
 [2] LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=ar_EG.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=ar_EG.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=ar_EG.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=ar_EG.UTF-8
[12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.2.0        htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.2.3    
[4] Rcpp_0.12.10    digest_0.6.12   xtable_1.8-2   
[7] httpuv_1.3.3    mime_0.5
```

The last logs in `shiny-server.log`

```
[32m[2017-04-12 16:45:34.506] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mShiny Server v1.5.3.838 (Node.js v6.10.0)
[32m[2017-04-12 16:45:34.509] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mUsing pidfile /var/run/shiny-server.pid
[32m[2017-04-12 16:45:34.510] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mUsing config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[32m[2017-04-12 16:45:34.554] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mStarting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
[32m[2017-04-12 17:24:34.766] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mStopping listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
[32m[2017-04-12 17:24:34.812] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mShutting down worker processes (with notification)
[32m[2017-04-12 17:25:01.677] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mShiny Server v1.5.3.838 (Node.js v6.10.0)
[32m[2017-04-12 17:25:01.680] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mUsing pidfile /var/run/shiny-server.pid
[32m[2017-04-12 17:25:01.681] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mUsing config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[33m[2017-04-12 17:25:01.758] [WARN] shiny-server - [39mRunning as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[32m[2017-04-12 17:25:01.762] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mStarting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
```

Comment: Try `http://localhost:3838`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel
Thanks. It is working!
This was kind of a simple Q, I had to figure it out.
I think I just tried it at a certain phase with https:// localhost:3838/ and had an issue so got back to the welcome.html to test.